# How to write Onenote 2010 equations on same line (unstacked ratio expression)?

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2010

Onenote 2010 offers 2 methods to display equations:
*Linear*  and *Professional*

"Professional" displays superscript/subscript AND ratio expressions in their natural math form.
"Linear" collapses everything on the same line.

For example, I want to write x^2 + y/2 + z^3
As soon as as hit SPACE or PLUS following y/2 , y/2 is displayed as stacked ratio.
How do I write x^2 and z^3 in superscript form , but keep y/2 as is, unstacked ratio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

write your whole equation, then go back and highlight the y/2 stack ratio (the WHOLE stacked ratio), and click linear.[image]

Comment: That was easy :) I didn't know I can change to linear just a part of the equation.